# Using Makefile for Stroustup's book

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm reading Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++".
Trying to compile the following example in Visual Studio I get four Linker errors. But then I realize that I'm not using the makefile which his website provides ([here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/)). This is the example I am trying to compile:

```
#include "../../Simple_window.h"
#include "../../Graph.h"
#include "../../Point.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;

    Point tl(100,100);

    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas");

    /*Polygon poly;
    poly.add(Point(300,200));
    poly.add(Point(350,100));
    poly.add(Point(400,200));

    poly.set_color(Color::red);

    win.attach(poly);*/

    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

How should I use the Makefile? Should I put in the same directory that the headers and cpp files and include it in the code?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Place it in the same directory as your code and then run `make` in that directory from the command line. Definitely do not include the makefile into your source files. It looks like you have your `main.cpp` file two directories deeper than the code supplied by Stroustrup, but it should probably be in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How should I run the makefile from the command line?

Comment: @nachogsiri You just run the command `make`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I open the cmd and navigate through the file and open it but it tell me that it is not a program. I change the extension to .win and now it opens like a txt file. The same occurs if I double click it

Comment: @nachogsiri Oh, you're on Windows. Make is typically used on UNIX-like operating systems. On those systems, you would have a makefile called `Makefile` and, if you have the program Make installed, you can just run the command `make`. Don't attempt to rename the makefile to anything else. It *is* a text file that describes how to build the program. Make is the program that knows how to understand it. If you want to use Make on Windows, you might want to install cygwin (a linux-like environment for Windows). Alternatively, you can just not use the makefile and just make a VS project or whatever.